# zeromq conversion between datatypes

Tags: c++, c++11, zeromq

Hello I am trying to understand and learn how to work with ZeroMQ and while this could be basic, I didn't find a way to fix it. In this code, I am trying to create a server to forward messages from one client to another one. The server compiled just fine but there are some major issues (almost all of them regarding datatypes) so I couldn't even test my server.

**server.cpp:**

```
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>    
int main ()
{
    zmq::message_t board (9);
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket1 (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket1.bind ("tcp://*:20000");
    zmq::socket_t socket2 (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket1.bind ("tcp://*:20001");
    int jogo=9;
    while (jogo)
    {
        zmq::message_t request;
        if (jogo%2!=0)
        {
            socket1.recv (&request);
            memcpy ((void *) board.data (), request.data(), 9);
            socket2.send (board);
        }
        else
        {
            socket2.recv (&request);
            memcpy ((void *) board.data (), request.data(), 9);
            socket1.send (board);
        }
        --jogo;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**jogo_client.cpp**

```
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int player,port=20000,jogo=9,ganhou=0;
    std::string game;
    std::cin >> player;
    port+=player;
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    std::cout << "Connecting to game server…" << std::endl;
    //-std=gnu++11
    socket.connect (std::string("tcp://localhost:")+std::to_string(port)); 
    zmq::message_t board (9);
    if(player)
    {
        while(jogo)
        {
            if (jogo%2!=0)
            {
                memcpy ((void *) board.data (), "Hi from 1", 9);
                std::cout << "Sending Hi" << std::endl;
                socket.send (board);
            }
            else
            {
                socket.recv (&board);
                memcpy ((void *) ,game, request.data (), 9);
                std::cout << "Got from 2: " << std::endl;
                std::cout << game << std::endl;
            }
            --jogo;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(jogo)
        {
            if (jogo%2!=0)
            {
                socket.recv (&board);
                memcpy ((void *) ,game, request.data (), 9);
                std::cout << "Getting from 2 " << std::endl;
                std::cout << game << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                emcpy ((void *) board.data (), "Hi from 2", 9);
                std::cout << "Sending Hi" << std::endl;
                socket.send (board);
            }
            --jogo;
        }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

compile errors:

```
jogo_client.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
jogo_client.cpp:14:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘zmq::socket_t::connect(std::basic_string<char>)’
jogo_client.cpp:14:73: note: candidate is:
In file included from jogo_client.cpp:1:0:
zmq.hpp:384:21: note: void zmq::socket_t::connect(const char*)
zmq.hpp:384:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’
jogo_client.cpp:29:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
jogo_client.cpp:29:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
jogo_client.cpp:43:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
jogo_client.cpp:43:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
```

Comment: this is pretty old, but what version of cppzmq do you have? Looking at `/usr/include/zmq.hpp` I see an overload of `zmq::socket_t::connect(std::string cont&)`. Of course, you do have a blatant coding error on line 29, so all bets are off.